# Simple pyautogui code works in IDLE, but not in a .py program

Tags: python

Python noob here - I want to create a program that tells me where the 8 key is on the Windows Calculator program on my screen.

First, I took a screenshot of the 8 key on the calculator and named it eightKey.png. This PNG file is stored in D:\

In IDLE, I created the following code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('D:\eightKey.png')
```

This code returns the co-ordinates of the 8 key on the calculator perfectly.

When I save this exact same code into a .py program and run it, no co-ordinates are returned. Everything is the exact same, including the calculator on screen.

I don't know why this is. If the code in IDLE is the exact same as the program, why doesn't the program work?

Comment: check your image path once, is it in the same dir ? post errors if you are getting any.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried making sure the path is D:\\ by doing the following:

`import pyautogui
import os
os.chdir('D:\\')
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('eightKey.png')`

However nothing is returning. When I do this in IDLE I get the co-ordinates of the 8 key perfectly. I'm making sure the path leads to the image in both IDLE and the .py program.